# Issue with Responsive Background Image on Screens <= 768px

Tags: css, background-image, responsive

I am encountering a problem with making my background image responsive, specifically on screens with a width of 768 pixels or less. The background image appears to be getting cropped more and more as I resize the screen to smaller widths.

```
body {
  background-image: url('./img/moods.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I have tried using the background-size: cover; property to ensure the background image covers the entire viewport, but the issue persists. I've reviewed various examples and tutorials, and most of them suggest the same approach.

What I've Tried:
I have experimented with different values for background-size and attempted to use media queries to address the problem, but none of my attempts have provided a satisfactory solution.

Comment: `background-size: cover` will scale the image, so that it covers the element in width _and_ height. If the aspect ratio of the image doesn't match that of the element, then _of course_ the image will get cropped, in whichever dimension the scaled version exceeds the available display area.

Comment: Are you saying that the image does not cover the whole of the body? How are the body’s dimensions set?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on displaying the *complete*  background image and at the same time have it cover the *whole* screen, you can use `background-size: 100% 100%;`.

However, in most cases this will distort the image, so this is only useful for abstract graphics (if at all), definitely not for photos.

Keep in mind that most mobile devices have a higher height than width (= "portrait orientation) as opposed to desktop and laptop screens where you have the opposite situation ("landscape orientation"). If you can use the same photo for both when using `background-size: cover` will depend on the photo itself. Using `background-position: center` can help here if the main motive of the photo is in its center and there is less important content around it, but not always. (note also @CBroes comment to your question)

Answer (score -1):

To make the background image responsive and prevent it from getting cropped on smaller screens, you can use the `background-position` property. By setting it to `center`, the background image will be centered on the screen and won't get cropped as the screen size decreases. Here's an updated CSS snippet:

css

```
body {
  background-image: url('./img/moods.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

This should help maintain the aspect ratio of the background image and ensure it is fully visible on screens with a width of 768 pixels or less.

Comment: How can an image which doesn't have the same aspect ratio as the viewport be accommodated? It will have to be cropped either at the sides or top and bottom.